# Vaadin: MouseDown/MouseUp and KeyDown/KeyUp evens

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible to handle MouseDown/MouseUp and KeyDown/KeyUp evens with Vaadin? I've found [forum thread](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2343644) with the same question and looks like the answer is no, but it was 5 years ago - I hope something changed with later releases. Still I can't find anything in API. Maybe there's some workaround for intercepting such evens?

Comment: What Vaadin version are you using, and what components you'd like to add mouse and key listeners for?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: @Morfic, 8.1.0.beta1, Tree component.

Comment: As per the [docs, the `Tree`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-tree.html) supports out of the box item click and context click listener, and navigation with the `Up` and `Down` keys, as well as expansion and collapsing with the `Right` and `Left` keys. If you really need more than that (eg mouse down and mouse up as opposed to clicks), it would be helpful if you could provide a more detailed scenario.

Comment: @Morfic, well, at least I need multi-selection with Shift key, which is not available out of the box. So I was going to detect Shift pressing by myself.

Comment: Same doc page talks about [`handling selections and clicks`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-selection.html#datamodel.selection), so you could try switching to multi selection, add a selection-listener and see if it fits your needs. P.S. there's a v8.1.0.rc1 :-)

Comment: I'm already using multi-selection, but Shift-selection doesn't work :(

Comment: This article may help, https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html

Comment: I tried to implement Vaadin Extension for the `Tree` with KeyDownHandler, but this event hasn't been intercepted - I don't know why...

Comment: The event passed into the item click listener has `event.getMouseEventDetails().isShiftKey()` so you could take advantage of it and add a _crude_ recursive method to select all the nodes from the first clicked one to the second even 'tho It's not very pretty visually. You can give it a try, and if you run into issues I can provide a somewhat working example as an answer to at least get you started.

Comment: @Morfic, yes, I know. But it doesn't solve the problem for keyboard-selection, because `SelectionListener` doesn't bring `MouseEventDetails` and we can't get Shift state there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after couple of days I came up with the acceptable (for me) solution. Required component has to be wrapped with extension-interceptor (credits to @petey for an idea in the comments) with `KeyDownHandler` inside. But **the trick is not to add to the component itself** (because it can miss triggering), **but to the** `RootPanel`. So here's a working example.

Extension:

```
public class InterceptorExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    private boolean shiftKeyDown;

    public InterceptorExtension(Tree tree) {
        super.extend(tree);
        registerRpc((InterceptorExtensionServerRpc) state -> shiftKeyDown = state);
    }

    public boolean isShiftKeyDown() {
        return shiftKeyDown;
    }

}
```

ServerRpc:

```
public interface InterceptorExtensionServerRpc extends ServerRpc {

    void setShiftKeyDown(boolean state);

}
```

Connector:

```
@Connect(InterceptorExtension.class)
public class InterceptorExtensionConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

    @Override
    protected void extend(final ServerConnector target) {
        final InterceptorExtensionServerRpc rpcProxy = getRpcProxy(InterceptorTreeExtensionServerRpc.class);
        final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
        rootPanel.addDomHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                if (event.isShiftKeyDown()) {
                    rpcProxy.setShiftKeyDown(true);
                }
            }
        }, KeyDownEvent.getType());
        rootPanel.addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                if (!event.isShiftKeyDown()) {
                    rpcProxy.setShiftKeyDown(false);
                }
            }
        }, KeyUpEvent.getType());
    }

}
```

Then whenever you want you can get Shift-button state on the server-side via InterceptorExtension#isShiftKeyDown.