# How to get startPosition when Drag a widget (vaadin 8.3)?

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin7, vaadin8

I have a component in a panel, with `DragSourceExtension`, I can pass any data by `DragData`, but I can not get relativeX and Y with `DragStartEvent`.

- I can get relativeX and Y of end position with `DropEvent`.

In vaadin 7, with `DragAndDropWrapper.WrapperTransferable` (transferable), we can get relativeX and Y when start draging:

```
transferable.getMouseDownEvent().getClientX()
transferable.getMouseDownEvent().getClientY()
```

UPDATE: this is some part of code:

```
DropTargetExtension<AbsoluteLayout> absoluteLayoutDropTargetExtension = new DropTargetExtension<>(sceneLayout);
...
absoluteLayoutDropTargetExtension.addDropListener(event -> {
Optional<Object> source = event.getDragData();
int x = event.getMouseEventDetails().getRelativeX();
int y = event.getMouseEventDetails().getRelativeY();
```

with x and y is current mouse position, but I have not start position to calculate diff

UPDATE 2:
by this doc [Component and UI Extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html), I test extension example.

```
public class CapsLockWarning extends AbstractExtension {
// You could pass it in the constructor
public CapsLockWarning(PasswordField field) {
    super.extend(field);
    System.out.println("CapsLockWarning");
}

// Or in an extend() method
public void extend(PasswordField field) {
    super.extend(field);
}

// Or with a static helper
public static void addTo(PasswordField field) {
    new CapsLockWarning(field);
}
```

}

```
@Connect(CapsLockWarning.class)
public class CapsLockWarningConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

public CapsLockWarningConnector() {
    super();
    System.out.println("CapsLockWarningConnector");
}

@Override
protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
    // Get the extended widget
    final Widget pw = ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();

    // Preparations for the added feature
    final VOverlay warning = new VOverlay();
    warning.setOwner(pw);
    warning.add(new HTML("Caps Lock is enabled!"));
    Window.alert("ssss");

    // Add an event handler
    pw.addDomHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            if (isEnabled() && isCapsLockOn(event)) {
                warning.showRelativeTo(pw);
                UiUtilities.showMessage("oh");
            } else {
                warning.hide();
            }
        }
    }, KeyPressEvent.getType());
}

private boolean isCapsLockOn(KeyPressEvent e) {
    return e.isShiftKeyDown() ^
            Character.isUpperCase(e.getCharCode());
}
```

}

UI:

```
    txtPassword = new PasswordField(bundle.getString("common.password"));
    txtPassword.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
    binder.forField(txtPassword).asRequired(MessageFormat.format(bundle.getString("common.error.isRequiredFor"), bundle.getString("common.password")))
            .bind(HostEntity::getPassword, HostEntity::setPassword);
    txtPassword.addStyleName("inline-label");
    new CapsLockWarning(txtPassword);
    form.addComponent(txtPassword);
```

but, `CapsLockWarningConnector`'s constructor did'nt run and no action happen in UI

Comment: I think you need to create some sort of an extension for that. But what for do you need X,Y? What is the actual problem?

Comment: @pirho I need to create a map and make a json to save an load it. for this reason, i need x and y of all objects.

Comment: Just some custom implementation or OL / Leaflet map?

Comment: @pirho lets I ask another question: how move an image (for example) that added to an absolutepanel from a position to another? do I need to reset top and left of image on addDropListener method of DropTargetExtension?

Comment: I can try to answer but it would be better if you updated your question and added some code what  you are currently trying - like in the above comments example - and where you are stuck. I am not sure what you mean by _resetting_?

Comment: @pirho some part of code was  added

Comment: Ok, I was guessing the same. It seems that you need the MouseDown event. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45056632/6413377) might help you.

Comment: @pirho: please see the Updte